# What are the number of ways of seating $n$ people around a circular table labelled from $1$ to n such that $3$ of them must be seated together?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The full question (How to count by Robert A. Beeler) is as follows:

> Suppose that we have $n$ people (where $n \geq 3$) to be seated around a circular dinner table with $n$ seats labelled $1, \ldots, n$. Three of the guests, Alice, Bob, and Chad must all be seated together in some order. In how many ways can this be
> done?

I have found a solution but that doesn't match with the answer and unfortunately, I cannot find a problem in my logic, here it is:

i. We can group Alice, Bob and Chad as a single object O, then the total number of objects we have to arrange is
$$(n - 3 + 1) = (n-2)$$

[$-3$ from removing the $3$ people and $+1$ from adding that grouped object]

ii. Because the table is labelled, it means that every single arrangement will be unique, thus there won't be any symmetries in reflections or rotations.

ii. The total number of ways comes out to be $$(n-2)!$$

iii. Now these $3$ people can be arranged themselves in the group as $3! = 6$

Thus my solution leads to the number of ways as $$6(n-2)!$$

Here is the book's solution:

i. Choose three places for Alice, Bob, and Chad. Since the table is circular, there are $n$ ways to do this.

ii.  Seat Alice, Bob, and Chad. There are $3! = 6$ ways to do this.

iii. Seat the remaining guests. There are $(n − 3)!$ ways to do this.
By the Multiplication Principle, there are $$6n(n − 3)!$$

I do understand this solution, but I don't understand why my solution doesn't match with the book's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your attempt, when you opted to treat the three guests who must sit together as a block, you reduced the number of objects from $n$ to $n - 2$.  Consequently, you had $n - 2$ ways to place the block.  However, there are actually $n$ possible starting positions for the block.  To compensate for this, you must multiply your answer by $\frac{n}{n - 2}$, which yields
$$\frac{n}{n - 2} \cdot 6(n - 2)! = 6n(n - 3)!$$
which agrees with the answer in you book.

Comment: very nice +1 , i think the main mistake of OP is to think this question like classical round table question where seats are indistinguishable. If the seats are not labeled as $1,2,..n$ , then the answer of OP is correct , but because of it is labeled , we chose one position as starting point of block , so $(n \times 3!)$, after that we had $(n-3)$ labeled seats to place $(n-3)$ people , it is just a permutation question. The $\color{red}{crucial}$ point is $\color{blue}{\text{seats labeled}}$

Comment: @Bulbasaur If the seats are not labeled, there would be $3!(n - 3)!$ distinguishable arrangements due to rotational invariance.  Choose any three consecutive seats for Alice, Bob, and Chad (it does not matter which three seats we pick due to rotational invariance).  Alice, Bob, and Chad can be arranged in those three seats in $3!$ ways.  The remaining $n - 3$ people can be arranged in the remaining $n - 3$ seats in $(n - 3)!$ ways as we proceed clockwise around the table from the block of three seats we filled with Alice, Bob, and Chad.

Comment: Yeah , it is my mistake , thanks for warning..